# Can not edit the object after is fetched from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas, fabricjs

[Project](https://jsfiddle.net/kenneb/zpo9aj7n/). When you type in the input field and the text on the shirt . Then press the button "see back" there is a downside.
Then click on the button "see front" and enter text in the input. Old text is saved , and the new is superimposed on top of it .
Question:
How to realize that the text would not overlap, and edited one that was introduced earlier?

```
   var canvas;
    var a;
    var b;
    var line1;
    var line2;
    var line3;
    var line4;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('FrontCanvas');

    $('#your-name').on('click', function() {
        clearCanvas();
        initTextString();
        $('#text-string').val('Your name')
    });

    var textSample;
    /*#text-string*/
    $('#text-string').on('keyup', function() {
        var text = $('#text-string').val();
        var activeText = canvas.getActiveObject();

        textSample = new fabric.Text(text, {
            originX: 'left',
            originY: 'top',
            fontSize: 32,
            fontFamily: 'MotorCyr',
            angle: 0,
            fontWeight: '',     
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: true,
            top: 50
        });

        canvas.setActiveObject(textSample);
        canvas.remove(activeText); 
        canvas.renderAll();
        canvas.add(textSample);
        canvas.centerObjectH(textSample);   
        $('#position').show();
        $("#removePrint").show();       
        if(document.getElementById('text-string').value.replace(/\s+/g, '').length < 1) {
            $('#position').hide();
            $("#removePrint").hide();   
        }
    });
    /*#text-string*/

    function initTextString() {
        var text = $('#text-string').val();

        textSample = new fabric.Text(text, {
            originX: 'left',
            originY: 'top',
            fontSize: 32,
            fontFamily: 'MotorCyr',
            angle: 0,
            fontWeight: '',     
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: true,
            top: 50
        });
        canvas.setActiveObject(textSample);
        canvas.renderAll();
        canvas.add(textSample);
        canvas.centerObjectH(textSample);   
        $('#position').show();
        $("#removePrint").show();   

        if(document.getElementById('text-string').value.replace(/\s+/g, '').length < 1) {
            $('#position').hide();
            $("#removePrint").hide();   
        }
    }




    document.getElementById("text-string").addEventListener("focusout", deactivateAll);
    document.getElementById("text-string").addEventListener("focus", focusText);

    function deactivateAll() {
        canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
    }
    function focusText() {
        if(textSample != undefined) {
            canvas.setActiveObject(textSample)
        }
    }






    $('#removePrint').on({
        click: function() {
            clearCanvas();
            $("#text-string").val("");
            $("#number-string").val("");
            $('#removePrint').hide();
            $('#position').hide();
        }
    });

    $(".printArea").hover(
        function() {                
            canvas.add(line1);
            canvas.add(line2);
            canvas.add(line3);
            canvas.add(line4); 
            canvas.renderAll();
        },
        function() {                
            canvas.remove(line1);
            canvas.remove(line2);
            canvas.remove(line3);
            canvas.remove(line4);
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
        );



    $('#flip').click(function() {   

        if ($(this).attr("data-title") == "Показать вид сзади") {

            var backSRC = $('#mainCanvas img').attr('data-back');
            console.log(backSRC);
            $(this).attr('data-title', 'Показать вид спереди');      
            $(this).text('See front');                                 
            $("#mainCanvas img").attr("src",backSRC);                   
            a = JSON.stringify(canvas);
            canvas.clear();
            try
            {
                var json = JSON.parse(b);

                canvas.loadFromJSON(b);
                canvas.loadFromJSON(b, function() {
                    canvas.renderAll();
                    console.log(canvas.item(0).name);
                }); 
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.log( e.name );
                console.log( e.message );
            }


        } else {
            var frontSRC = $('#mainCanvas img').attr('data-front');
            console.log(frontSRC);
            $(this).attr('data-title', 'Показать вид сзади');
            $(this).text('See back');                                       
            $("#mainCanvas img").attr("src",frontSRC);

            b = JSON.stringify(canvas);
            canvas.clear();
            try
            {
                var json = JSON.parse(a);
                canvas.loadFromJSON(a, function() {
                    canvas.renderAll();
                    console.log(canvas.item(0).name);
                });                
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.log( e.name );
                console.log( e.message);
            }
        }       
    canvas.renderAll();
    setTimeout(function() {
        canvas.calcOffset();
    },200);             
});    


line1 = new fabric.Line([0,0,200,0], {"stroke":"#000000", "strokeWidth":1,hasBorders:false,hasControls:false,hasRotatingPoint:false,selectable:false});
line2 = new fabric.Line([199,0,200,399], {"stroke":"#000000", "strokeWidth":1,hasBorders:false,hasControls:false,hasRotatingPoint:false,selectable:false});
line3 = new fabric.Line([0,0,0,400], {"stroke":"#000000", "strokeWidth":1,hasBorders:false,hasControls:false,hasRotatingPoint:false,selectable:false});
line4 = new fabric.Line([0,400,200,399], {"stroke":"#000000", "strokeWidth":1,hasBorders:false,hasControls:false,hasRotatingPoint:false,selectable:false});

});//doc ready

function clearCanvas() {
    canvas.clear().renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call loadFromJson a new fabric text is created, you should attach the input #text-string with this new text when you call loadFromJSON and unlink #text-string from the old text object when you stringify canvas

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(a, function() {
  canvas.getObjects() //get the new text here and attach to input text
});
```

BTW, fabricjs has an itext object where you can type directly in the object

Comment: I am contributed a project with your changes, but this did not help me.

Comment: I did not implement it, just showed where to change

Comment: I implement it here https://jsfiddle.net/kenneb/zpo9aj7n/  , but your code didn't work